# What's a word for someone being a tease or playful?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, epithet-requests

Is there a "clean" (non-sexual) word for someone who acts all playful and provocative just so they can get your attention and your compliments?

I guess coquettish comes close, but its meaning seems to be sexual in nature (akin to "tease").

Comment: Generally speaking, he's "being a tease" or simply "teasing".  Why do you need another word?

Comment: How will you use the word? Can you write an example sentence? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @HotLicks, yes, I know that I can simply say "being a tease", but I thought that word has a sexual connotation to it?

Comment: @Rathony, Not sure how I can exactly put this in a sentence, I thought I was already clear enough? I'll try the best I can to show an example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I voted to close without noticing your recent edit. I have now voted to reopen it.

Comment: There is hardly a word in the English language that can't have a sexual connotation to it, in the "proper" context.

Comment: I really opt for this question to be open again. How does it differ from the other ones? Not sure how I can edit the question to suit the needs of the admins here.

Comment: From the [help]: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? **Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.** This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get a more specific and relevant answer.

Comment: There is no answer to this question, because you CLOSED the question. It's ON HOLD. You only allowed one answer here. This is just beyond ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

Children and/or animals who "perform" for attention are often described as "a (little) *ham*."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ham

Comment: Interesting that this has a definition almost exactly like the way I imagined it. Would've been a lot better if it was called something other than "ham" btw. :/

Comment: You guys forgot to mention words like "pamper" and "coddle". Took me 6 months to find these words.